# How do I detect if a Firebase Storage file exists?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I'm writing a Swift extension on `FIRStorageReference` to detect if a file exists or not. I am calling `metadataWithCompletion()`. If the completion block's optional `NSError` is not set, I think it's safe to assume that the file exists.

If the NSError is set, either something went wrong or the file doesn't exist. The [storage documentation on handling errors in iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/handle-errors) states that `FIRStorageErrorCodeObjectNotFound` is the type of error that I should be checking, but is doesn't resolve (possibly Swiftified into a shorter .Name-style constant?) and I'm not sure what I should be checking it against.

I'd like to be calling `completion(nil, false)` if `FIRStorageErrorCodeObjectNotFound` is set somewhere.

Here's my code so far.

```
extension FIRStorageReference {
    func exists(completion: (NSError?, Bool?) -> ()) {
        metadataWithCompletion() { metadata, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("Error.code: \(error.code)")

                // This is where I'd expect to be checking something.

                completion(error, nil)
                return
            } else {
                completion(nil, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: We intentionally didn't build an "object existence check" since we figure checking the error code for `FIRStorageErrorCodeObjectNotFound` on object get or metadata get was good enough. Can you give me a little more rationale behind why you want this functionality as opposed to just doing the object/metadata get and handling the error if the desired object isn't found?

Comment: Getting the metadata is a fine approach, what I'm now not sure about is how I'm meant to determine which error is happening. In my code, what would I do with this NSError object and, if there is no error object, is it safe to assume the file exists? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the error code like so:

```
// Check error code after completion
storageRef.metadataWithCompletion() { metadata, error in
  guard let storageError = error else { return }
  guard let errorCode = FIRStorageErrorCode(rawValue: storageError.code) else { return }
  switch errorCode {
    case .ObjectNotFound:
      // File doesn't exist

    case .Unauthorized:
      // User doesn't have permission to access file

    case .Cancelled:
      // User canceled the upload

    ...

    case .Unknown:
    // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it still counts as a "read" or request if it delivers `.ObjectNotFound`?

Comment: No. From the GCS docs (https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing), "Note: Generally, you are not charged for operations that return 307, 4xx, or 5xx responses. The exception is 404 responses returned by buckets with Website Configuration enabled and the NotFoundPage property set to a public object in that bucket."

Comment: Nice - at least Google’s got your back for that  thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Thats a simple code that I use to check if user has already got a user photo by hasChild("") method ,and the reference is here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html

hope this can help

```
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        self.databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                let username = snapshot.value!["username"] as! String
                self.userNameLabel.text = username
                // check if user has photo
                if snapshot.hasChild("userPhoto"){
                    // set image locatin
                    let filePath = "\(userID!)/\("userPhoto")"
                    // Assuming a < 10MB file, though you can change that
                    self.storageRef.child(filePath).dataWithMaxSize(10*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                        let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.userPhoto.image = userPhoto
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, but `hasChild()` and the documentation you mention both refer to the Firebase's *Database*. I'm trying to detect a file's presence in Firebase's Storage. I think these are quite separate.

Comment: sorry for not being more specific, when you storage a file to FIRsotrage then it will produce a URL , I use FIRdatabase to storage this URL as a reference, So I can just check if this URL is exist that I can know the file is also exist.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems like a workaround rather than a correct way of doing this. I was hoping there'd be some way I could decipher the reason for the error programatically in `metadataWithCompletion()` but it's not obvious how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("yourPath").child("\(someFile)") // eg. someVideoFile.mp4

print(storageRef.fullPath) // use this to print out the exact path that your checking to make sure there aren't any errors

storageRef.getMetadata() { (metadata: StorageMetadata?, error) in
        
    if let error = error {
        guard let errorCode = (error as NSError?)?.code else {
            print("problem with error")
            return
        }
        guard let err = StorageErrorCode(rawValue: errorCode) else {
            print("problem with error code")
            return
        }
        switch err {
           case .objectNotFound:
                print("File doesn't exist")
            case .unauthorized:
                print("User doesn't have permission to access file")
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled the download")
            case .unknown:
                print("Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response")
            default:
                print("Another error occurred. This is a good place to retry the download")
        }
        return
    }
        
    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        // an error occured while trying to retrieve metadata
        print("metadata error")
        return
    }
        
    if metadata.isFile {
        print("file must exist becaus metaData is a file")
    } else {
        print("file for metadata doesn't exist")
    }
        
    let size = metadata.size
    if size != 0 {
        print("file must exist because this data has a size of: ", size)
    } else {
        print("if file size is equal to zero there must be a problem"
    }
}
```

A shorter version without the detailed error check:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("yourPath").child("\(someFile)")
storageRef.getMetadata() { (metadata: StorageMetadata?, error) in
        
    if let error = error { return }
    
    guard let metadata = metadata else { return }
        
    if metadata.isFile {
        print("file must exist because metaData is a file")
    } else {
        print("file for metadata doesn't exist")
    }
        
    let size = metadata.size
    if size != 0 {
        print("file must exist because this data has a size of: ", size)
    } else {
        print("if file size is equal to zero there must be a problem"
    }
}
```