# Check Firebase Storage before creating a new profile Image URL

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, image-caching

I am having a bit of an issue checking Firebase Storage when a user logs into my app. When a user logs in an image is created and stored successfully in Firebase database and storage, but every time a user logs out and logs back into the app the profileImage file (not the child value url string) is duplicated in Firebase Storage as a new and separate image file.

I would like the app when logging in to check the Firebase storage for the profileImage file, and if it exists then do not re-create that same image in storage. I understand the logic of checking Firebase for image and if does not exist, than create new image. I am just having some trouble with the syntax. Thanks for help in advance!

```
// login user with Facebook
func loginWithFacebook() {
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }

    let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Something went wrong with our FB user: ", error ?? "")
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }

        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png")
        let photoUrl = user?.photoURL

        // check to see if current user already has stored image with URL
        if FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png") == nil {

            if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: photoUrl!) {
                storageRef.put(imageData as Data, metadata:nil) {
                    (metadata, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    } else {

                        if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                            let values = ["name": user!.displayName!, "email": user!.email!, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
                            self.registerUserWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("image already exists")
        }

        print("Successfully logged in with our user: ", user ?? "")
        self.delegate?.finishLoggingIn()

      })

private func registerUserWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    // create items in database upon creating user ---------------
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
            return
        }
        print("user has been saved to Firebase database")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the "if" condition. You are referencing the location, but not checking with the actual data in that location.

You can implement that using .observerSingleEventOf().

```
private func checkUser (imageName:String, _ completionHandler: @escaping(Bool) -> Void)
  {
    let userExists = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profile_images")
    userExists.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{(snapshot) in
      if snapshot.hasChild(imageName){
        print ("Image already exists")
        completionHandler(false)
      }
      else
      {
      print ("Image does not exist")
      print ("store the image")
      }
    })
  }
```

`

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. But I am still getting an error "Value of type 'FIRStorageReference' has no member 'observeSingleEvent'... any thoughts on why?

Comment: @user3708224 sorry I thought it's for firebase database. Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184900/how-do-i-detect-if-a-firebase-storage-file-exists.