# Change View if a file doesn't exist

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-storage

I'm trying to check if a user has a profile picture (retrieved from Firebase Storage) and if not to show to the user a specific view.

At the moment I'm only checking if the user is logged in and if so it is displaying my TabViews.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

struct ContentView: View {


func getUser() {
    session.listen()
}

@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore


var body: some View {
    Group {
        if (session.session != nil) {
            HostingTabView()
        }
        else {
            AuthView()
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: getUser)
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore())
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to find if the user has the following image saved in the firebase storage and if so to display another view.

```
let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(id).child("profilePic.png")
```

I'm unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of useful answers here for checking if a file exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62982782/560942

I'll use the shorter one here as an example, but I'd suggest you use the longer one with more robust error handling -- the principal will be the same either way.

```
class FirebaseManager : ObservableObject {

  @Published var profilePicExists = false

  func checkForProfileImage() {
         let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("yourPath").child("\(someFile)")
storageRef.getMetadata() { (metadata: StorageMetadata?, error) in
        
        if let error = error { return }
    
        guard let metadata = metadata else { return }
        
        if metadata.isFile {
           print("file must exist because metaData is a file")
        } else {
          print("file for metadata doesn't exist")
        }
        
       let size = metadata.size
       if size != 0 {
         print("file must exist because this data has a size of: ", size)

         self.profilePicExists = true // <-- Here
       } else {
         print("if file size is equal to zero there must be a problem"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Then, to show a conditional view, you'd do a similar technique to what you're doing if a user is logged in:

```
var body: some View {
    if manager.profilePicExists {
       //profile pic view
    } else {
       //other view
    }
}
```

This is a pretty bare-bones example. In reality, you might want to have more states for what to display while the async `getMetadata` is *loading* and hasn't returned a value, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'm a little bit unsure on how to implement this within my code. I created the class FirbaseManager within my ContentView.swift file.However, Im unable to use manager.profilePicExists because it is out of scope. I guess I'm missing something fundamental in here.

Comment: `@StateObject private var manager = FirebaseManager()` -- you'll also have to call `checkForProfileImage()` on `onAppear` or something similar. Very similar technique to what I showed you in the previous answer earlier today.

Comment: I should also mention that you could probably just put this code in your `SessionStore` -- I assume it has data there about the user ID etc -- notice I left that out of my code as well.

Comment: It worked now adding the onAppear. Thank you so much!